# Hide the "left/right" and "down" arrow buttons in Sublime Text's tab bar

Tags: sublimetext3

The tab bar (the horizontal bar which holds the tab for each open file) also contains "left" and "right" arrow buttons on the left side, and one "down" arrow at the right side of the bar. These "left/right" buttons switch between which tab is active, and the "down" button opens a dropdown list of all open tabs.

[image: An example]

How can I disable or hide only these buttons, while still showing tabs in the tab bar?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/698212/how-to-disable-overlapping-tabs-or-scrolling-tabs-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: To replace this functionality, you can use <kbd>ctrl+tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+shift+tab<kbd> to navigate through active tabs, and <kbd>(ctrl|cmd)+p</kbd> or the "Toggle Open Files in Side Bar" command to list all active tabs vertically.

Answer (score 12):

In *Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - User*, add the following line.

```
"enable_tab_scrolling": false,
```